# Equality and Assignment Operators

Tags: c#, vb.net, operators

I have an assembly compiled in VB.NET that contains two operators:

```
Public Shared Operator =(quarterA As CalendarQuarter, quarterB As CalendarQuarter) As Boolean
    Return quarterA.StartDate = quarterB.StartDate AndAlso
        quarterA.EndDate = quarterB.EndDate AndAlso
        quarterA.Quarter = quarterB.Quarter
End Operator

Public Shared Operator <>(quarterA As CalendarQuarter, quarterB As CalendarQuarter) As Boolean
    Return Not (quarterA = quarterB)
End Operator
```

However, when using the assembly in C# to perform equality checks `if (qtr != null)` I receive the error:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool'`

Usage in C# MVC4, Razor:

```
@{Html.BeginForm();}
    <div class="ui-form ui-form-horizontal form-width-narrow">
        <div class="title">
            Choose a Quarter</div>
        <div class="group">
            <label><strong>Control</strong></label>
            <div class="field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Quarter, new SelectList(Model.AvailableQuarters))
                <input value="Select" class="ui-button" type="submit" />
            </div>
        </div>
        @if (Model.Quarter != null) {
            // Error in the above statement 
        }           
    </div>
@{Html.EndForm();}
```

**What do I need to do to make the equality operator behave properly?**

Comment: Why are you talking about assignment? Your code doesn't contain any assignments. It's also not possible to overload assignment.

Comment: Could you give a short but *complete* example (the VB and the C#) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @CodesInChaos, you're right. I went through the code again and was mistaking it with another, unrelated bit. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I implement your code as-is and compare an instance to null I get a `NullReferenceException` in your equality operator.  However if I add a null check it works fine:

```
Public Shared Operator =(quarterA As CalendarQuarter, quarterB As CalendarQuarter) As Boolean

    If quarterA Is Nothing OrElse quarterB Is Nothing Then Return False

    Return quarterA.StartDate = quarterB.StartDate AndAlso
        quarterA.EndDate = quarterB.EndDate AndAlso
        quarterA.Quarter = quarterB.Quarter
End Operator
```

I suspect something else is causing the error you're getting.

Most likely you're using the assignment operator (`=`) when you should be using the equality operator (`==`):

```
if (qtr = null)   // wrong  - assigning null to qtr
if (qtr == null)  // correct
```

In addition, I would recommend [overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh.aspx) to be consistent with your equality operator.

Comment: Yep, that was it. The null check in the operator was needed. Oddly, after adding the null check to the operator, then removing it again to verify its effect, I started recieving the NullReferenceException just as you did. Not sure how I was getting the type conversion error before, but it's gone now. Thank you!

Comment: After some further testing, it looks like I also need to include `If quarterA Is Nothing And quarterB Is Nothing Then Return True` prior to the null check in the operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can't overload assignment operators, neither in VB or C#.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx